# Homomorphism space of permutation modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose that a finite group $G$ acts on two sets $X,Y$. Let $K[X]$ and $K[Y]$ denote the permutation modules (i.e. the $K[G]$-modules with multiplication given by the action of $G$, extended linearly), where $K$ is any field.

I am interested in the dimension of the $K$-vector space of $K[G]$-homomorphisms between these modules (i.e. $Hom_{K[G]}(K[X],K[Y])$).

Is there a nice way to compute the dimension? Say, the number orbits of $G$ on $X \times Y$ seems a good candidate but I am not sure.

Any idea? I was thinking about using matrices and checking when a linear map between the modules is a modules homomorphism. But I cannot make it work.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $T$ is any $K[G]$-module, then $\hom_{K[G]}(K[X],T)$ identifies with $\hom_G(X,U(T))$, where $U(-)$ is the forgetful functor from $K[G]$-modules to $G$-sets. If $X = \coprod_i X_i$ as $G$-sets, then $\hom_G(X,U(T)) \cong \prod_i \hom_G(X_i,U(T))$. Therefore, we may reduce the question to the case that $X$ is transitive, hence isomorphic to $G/H$ for some subgroup $H$ of $G$. If $Y$ is any $G$-set, then $\hom_G(G/H,Y)$ identifies (via $f \mapsto f([1])$) with those $y \in Y$ such that $H \subseteq G_y$.

Now consider $T=K[Y]$ for some $G$-set $Y$. The elements have the form $t = \sum_{y \in Y} \lambda_y \cdot y$ for uniquely determined $\lambda_y \in K$, almost all zero. We have $g \in G_t$ if and only if $\lambda_{gy}=\lambda_y$ for all $y \in Y$.

Therefore, $\hom_{K[G]}(K[X],K[Y])$ identifies, when $X=G/H$, with $K[H/Y]$. The dimension is the number of $H$-orbits in $Y$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a "constructive way" to find the subgroup $H$ in the above? Also, isn't the number of "H"-orbits in $Y$ equal to the number of $G$-orbits of $X \times Y$?

Comment: $H$ is a stabilizer group of $X$.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I was only wondering if there is a way to find $H$ without having to do some (often messy) calculations (to find such $H$). Thanks anyway!